# Return desde una función anónima

Tags: javascript, imagen, function

Buenas tardes.

Me gusta hacer las cosas por mi mismo para aprender, pero parte del aprendizaje también consiste en pedir ayuda, como ahora hehehe.

Intento obtener con JavaScript las dimensiones de una imagen jpg de **700x700** px de una carpeta. El código tal y como lo tengo es este:

```js
let pag = new Image();
pag.src = 'images/page1.jpg';
pag.onload = function()
{
    ancho = this.width;
    alto = this.height;

    let medidas = new Array(2);
    medidas = [ancho, alto];

    return medidas;
}

let din = nombreFuncion();
console.log(din[0] + ' x ' + din[1]);
```

Pero no sé qué nombre de función debo indicar en las últimas líneas para que tome el valor del **return**. Me sale error que *nombreFuncion* no está definida (obviamente).

He probado haciendo con una función con nombre de este modo:

```js
let pag = new Image();
pag.src = 'images/page1.jpg';
pag.onload = scan_img(pag);

function scan_img(pag)
{
    ancho = pag.width;
    alto = pag.height;

    let medidas = new Array(2);
    medidas = [ancho, alto];

    return medidas;
}

let din = scan_img(pag);
console.log(din[0] + ' x ' + din[1]);
```

Pero el problema en este caso es que no sale error, pero en el console.log me sale que las dimensiones son **0x0** y si refresco la página ya toma los **700x700**.

Pero yo no quiero que los tome cuando refresque la página, quiero que tome las dimensiones desde que se abre por primera vez. Ya que necesito esas dimensiones para maquetar un libro virtual. Con el código del principio se toman sin problema, pero no sé que nombre debo poner para tomar el valor del return.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo,

Germán

Comment: El segundo código no es correcto. Al  pag.onload le puedes asignar una referencia de función, con ese código realmetne se ejecuta scan_img(pag) y le asigna el resultado (medidas) a page.onload. El primer código es correcto, pero de nada te vale el return, el resultado no es asignable. Lo que puedes hacer es guardar el resultado en un objeto global para usarlo más adelante (cuando ya se ha cargado la imagen). Depende de que quieras hacer exactamente. En lugar de return llama al script que use el resultado por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la versión en Ingles hay una pregunta parecida [image.onload function with return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434371/image-onload-function-with-return) ... puedes checar una de las respuestas, pero lo mejor es llamar a otra función desde el onload, no usar el return.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sí, el ejemplo me ha ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Parece un problema de carga, el script se ejecuta antes de que se cargue la imagen y por eso no lo detecta. He realizado pruebas con tu código y funciona bien, pero tienes que colocarlo ante de la etiqueta de cierre del body.

Te paso tu codigo resumido:

```
        let pag = new Image();
        pag.src = 'assets/cartas/2C.png';
        
        const scan_img = (pag) => {
        
            let medidas = [pag.width, pag.height];
            return medidas;
        }

        let din = scan_img(pag);
        console.log(din[0] + ' x ' + din[1]);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. Pero sí que la pongo antes del </body>. No me funciona ni poniendo el spript en el head.